# For loop - double variable using single file as input

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm familiar with a basic for loop. Such as one like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts=$(< file)

for h in $hosts; do "some-command" "$h"
done
```

But..I have a formatted text file that was created with the paste command and arranged into two columns.

```
 paste file1 file2 | column -s $'\t' -t > combinedfile
```

And that file looks like this:

```
line1column1               line1column2       
line2column1               line2column2 
line3column1               line3column2
```

What I need is feed this file into a for loop script and pass in each line one at a time, using column1's data as the first variable and column2's data as the second variable.

Something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts=$(< file)

for h i in $hosts; do "some-command" "$h" "i"
done
```

Where "h" is equal to line 1 column 1 and "i" is equal to line one column 2. What is the right way to do this?

UPDATE: while using Tom's approach I setup my script but it worked on the first line then quit.

Here is what I have setup:

```
#!/bin/bash

doit="/pathtocommand"
file="/pathtosourcefile"

while read -r username password; do

$doit "$username" "$password"

done < $file
```

Ideas?

UPDATE 2:

I wanted to post my expect script as well. This is the "command" that is ran in the while loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f 

## Set up variables to be passed in as command line arguments
#set username [lindex $argv 0];
#set password [lindex $argv 1];
lassign $argv username password

spawn telnet 192.168.100.101 106
expect "200 PWD Server ready"    
send "USER user\r"
expect "300 please send the PASS"
send "PASS password\r"
expect "200 login OK, proceed"

## Use the line below for passwords that do not have to be enclosed with quotes
send "SETACCOUNTPASSWORD $username PASSWORD $password\r"

# Use the line below for a password that must be quoted ie one that   contains a $ or a ! by escaping the double quotes
#send "SETACCOUNTPASSWORD $username PASSWORD \"$password\"\r"

expect "200 OK"
send "quit\r"
interact
```

I have used this same expect script in the past with SSH and a regular for loop with no issues. Could it be something in my expect script that I need to modify or change?

Comment: Does the script work with `doit=echo` ?

Comment: doit=echo works. So it must be something in the expect script that it does not like. I've done this though with ssh with no problems just not with  telnet. I wonder if thats the problem.

Comment: Now try little steps. Will it work when your masterscript calls `$doit` twice without a while-loop? If it does, perhaps you need to keep stdin reserved for the expect loop and try something like @chepner wrote, without the `host` stuff: `while IFS= read -r username password<&3; do $doit "$username" "$password"; done 3< file`.

Answer (score 3):

The way to perform a set of actions for every line in a file is to use a `while read` loop:

```
while read -r host something_else; do
    some_command "$host" "$something_else"
done < file
```

Each line is split by the shell and the variables `$host` and `$something_else` are set to the values of the fields.

The `-r` option should almost always be used, since it tells the shell not to try and do anything clever with escape sequences in the input.

Comment: See ["How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for further reading.

Comment: It ran but did not go through the entire file. It just worked on the first line. IN the file I am testing with, I have 25 lines. No errors or anything, it just quit.

Comment: @user53029, do you use `set -e` in your script?

Comment: I did not. see my updated post to show my script. Where do I place set -e?

Comment: @user53029 if you were using `set -e`, it could possibly explain the script exiting as you have described. I don't think that glenn was suggesting that you add it. If you add `set -x` before your loop, then you will be able to see the commands that are being executed, which may help you determine what's going wrong.

Comment: I add the set -x right above the line with while in it or add it to the line right before while?

Comment: @user53029 `set -x` is a command which you should run before the part of the code that is broken.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating the input file (and not just getting it from somewhere else), note that you can work with the original two files:

```
while IFS= read -r host && IFS= read -r i <&3; do
    some_command "$host" "$i"
done < file1 3< file2
```

Comment: I just got around to trying this method as well and it stops after the first line.